# How can I create a button that takes me back to a previous view?

Tags: iphone

In my current iPhone application, I have four views.  I would like to move from the first view to any of the three other views.

In one of these second views, how would I create a button that takes me back to the first view?

Comment: Hey folk are you using the single view controller or two,if you are using two or more view controllers then you can use UINavigation Controller and then on the button event you can pop and push the view.If you are using two views in a single view controller class then you can use views property like [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myview];  or  [self.view sendSubviewToBack:myview]; .Hope this helps you and I suggest you to go through UINavigationController's reference..

Comment: I tried to rewrite your question to be clearer, but I may not have understood what you were asking.  In the future, note that it is impolite to request that people send you the exact code to accomplish a task, something you have done for your last several questions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a UINavigationController:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UINavigationController/

Answer (score 0):

Also if you have a button that is not on the navbar that you want to act as your "back" button, you can always pop the current view. Something like

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This should work on a UIViewController which is on top of a UINavigationController.